# Getting data through an SSH tunnel using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ssh

I recently started to learn Hibernate technology and have to get data from a database using Hibernate. The problem is that I can connect to the database only via an SSH tunnel. Are there any properties which I can use in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file to solve this problem? Or may be you can suggest another way which will be understandable to a newbie.

Comment: Can you build a simple JDBC connection through this SSH tunnel? What DB do you use?

Comment: @Tichodroma , previosly I tried to connect to this MySQL database only manually, using MySQL clients...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe using [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). [Some examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) could give you a way to go.

Another way could be implementing your own SSH SocketFactory, maybe with http proxy handler and port forwarding stuff. A starting point could be:

```
SSHSocketFactory fact = new SSHSocketFactory(sshHost, sshPort, new SSHPasswordAuthenticator(sshUser, sshPassword));

sock = fact.createSocket(host, port);
```

And you could link your implementation with the following parameter inside your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file:

```
hibernate.connection.socketFactory=com.mysql.jdbc.NamedPipeSocketFactory
```

Or maybe like the way they do [here](http://code.google.com/p/sshframework/source/browse/trunk/src/cn/hs/ssh/test/hibernate/config/HibernateUtil.java?spec=svn2&r=2) or [here](http://www.codeforge.com/read/141861/HibernateSessionFactory.java__html) (the latter is the better way to go).

Good ssh stuff!

Comment: shared link(latter one) doesn't work anymore.