# Ssh connection to mysql server in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ssh

I have database in MySql 5 server, but it needs ssh connection.
I want to use hibernate but I don't know how to configure hibernate.cfg.xml file for connect to ssh server.
Of course, I tried to find the answer in google, but I did not find anything. 
Also I tried use Putty, but it's also not help.

Comment: Do you mean that your mysql server runs over ssh?

Comment: Are you using SSH to tunnel and "port forward" the connection ?  or are you really talking about using SSL with MySQL JDBC driver ?

Comment: Yes, I using SSH to tunnel and forward port for the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can use [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) for ssh hibernate, For examples about Jsch [clickhere](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/)

Here is the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317077/getting-data-through-an-ssh-tunnel-using-hibernate) it could help you to solve the SSH in hibernate.