# Hibernate through SSH

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ssh, jsch

How can I change my `hibernate.cfg.xml` to connect to a MySQL Server port 3306 on another machine through SSH port 22?

Is it possible to enter the SSH details into `hibernate.cfg.xml`? If not, is there a better way to do it?

I already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317077/getting-data-through-an-ssh-tunnel-using-hibernate) but it doesn't explain where the java code goes and how it links to the `hibernate.cfg.xml` code.

Comment: Out of the box MySQL supports SSL for encrypted connections. Why don't you use this?

Comment: How do I use it from my Hibernate Java application?

Comment: Have you tried the examples provided in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273403/how-can-i-configure-hibernate-to-use-ssl-to-talk-to-the-db-server)

Answer (score 1):

JSCH (Java Secure Channel). You can [use this](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).